# Kill child process when execvp fails in C function

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I have a function in C that creates a child process and uses `execvp()` to execute a certain task.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  if (execvp(cmd->arg_array[0], cmd->arg_array) == -1) {
    exit(-1);
    return ERROR;
  }
} else if (pid < 0)
  return ERROR;

//Some more code...
return NO_ERROR;
```

As you can see, if the task fails, the process containing it should be deleted and the function returned with `ERROR` value.

I tried implementing this functionality with an `exit(-1)` *(and `_exit()` also)*, but the return statement is never reached, since the code is in the parent process zone. Also, if I remove the `exit()` and let the function return the error, the process keeps existing and interferes with the program functioning. How can I kill the created child process before the function returns when `execvp` task fails?

Comment: "but the return statement is never reached, since the code is in the parent process zone" No it is not. `return ERROR;` is not reached because it is right after a call to `exit`, at which point the child process ceases to exist. It isn't clear why you think you need to kill anything. Just remove `return ERROR;`.

Comment: The parent process needs to use `wait()` or `waitpid()` or friends to get the child's exit status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the process containing it should be deleted and the function returned with `ERROR` value.

No, that's not what happens. A successful `fork()` creates a new process and returns `0` to this new process. In you example, `execvp` is executed in this new process and if it fails, you immediately do `exit(-1);`, at which point the process terminates and the line `return ERROR;` will never be reached.

You can collect the child's exit status in the parent process by using `wait` or `waitpid`. Use `WIFEXITED`/`WEXITSTATUS`, `WIFSIGNALED`/`WTERMSIG`, `WIFSTOPPED`/`WSTOPSIG` and `WIFCONTINUED` to unpack the information about how it exited (or stopped/continued).

Example:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    execvp(cmd->arg_array[0], cmd->arg_array);
    // there's no need to check the return value from execvp:
    // if execvp returns, it means that it failed.
    _exit(1); // use _exit() instead of exit() to abort when exec fails
} else if (pid == -1)
    return ERROR;
}

// parent
int wstatus;
pid_t child;

while( (child = wait(&wstatus)) != -1 ) {
    printf("child %ld died with status %d\n", (long)child, wstatus);
}
```

Note: The function `_exit()` is like `exit()`, but does not call any functions registered with `atexit()` or `on_exit()` and you probably wouldn't want those to be called just because `execvp` failed.

When a child process is created via `fork()`, it inherits copies of its parent's `on_exit` registrations. Upon a successful call to one of the `exec()` functions (like `execvp`), all registrations are removed.